# Firebase [FIRApp configure] crash after pod update

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, xcode9

My app was working great and I just have updated my Firebase pods to latest version and I started to get error in `AppDelegate` for `[FIRApp configure];`. Below is the crash log. What might be the problem?

Ps. I don't have Analytics in my podfile but it is existing as a folder under pods folder and app works well when I delete `[FirApp configure]`.

Podfile:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Crash log:

```
2017-10-04 20:38:56.259470+0300 App Name[1833:36427] 
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS024000] Debug mode is on
2017-10-04 20:38:56.259863+0300 App Name[1833:36427] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40004000 started
2017-10-04 20:38:56.260640+0300 App Name[1833:36427] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http:)
2017-10-04 20:38:56.260949+0300 App Name[1833:36427] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
2017-10-04 20:38:56.301947+0300 App Name[1833:36333] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null) is not class or protocol'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa161cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011627ff41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa8ab95 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   App Name                           0x000000010ce45798 -[TyphoonComponentFactory(InstanceBuilder) allDefinitionsForType:includeSubclasses:] + 184
    4   App Name                           0x000000010ce45409 -[TyphoonComponentFactory(InstanceBuilder) definitionForType:orNil:includeSubclasses:] + 121
    5   App Name                           0x000000010ce477ab -[TyphoonComponentFactory inject:] + 171
    6   App Name                           0x000000010ce69937 +[TyphoonStartup injectInitialFactoryIntoDelegate:] + 87
    7   App Name                           0x000000010ce69514 __60+[TyphoonStartup swizzleSetDelegateMethodOnApplicationClass]_block_invoke + 1044
    8   App Name                           0x000000010d0fa929 -[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy initWithApplication:] + 1589
    9   App Name                           0x000000010d0fb304 __41+[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 78
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011371543c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001137169c7 dispatch_once_f + 297
    12  App Name                           0x000000010d0fb2b4 +[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy sharedInstance] + 102
    13  App Name                           0x000000010d0f1852 -[FIRAuth initWithAPIKey:appName:] + 280
    14  App Name                           0x000000010d0f0cd4 -[FIRAuth initWithApp:] + 151
    15  App Name                           0x000000010d0f0c13 __23+[FIRAuth authWithApp:]_block_invoke + 51
    16  App Name                           0x000000010d11793e +[FIRAppAssociationRegistration registeredObjectWithHost:key:creationBlock:] + 354
    17  App Name                           0x000000010d0f0ba5 +[FIRAuth authWithApp:] + 152
    18  App Name                           0x000000010d0f07d6 __15+[FIRAuth load]_block_invoke_2 + 144
    19  Foundation                          0x0000000115ca19c9 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 303
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9b207c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9b1f7a _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9b1cc2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f973a32 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f972bac _CFXNotificationPost + 652
    25  Foundation                          0x0000000115c61842 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    26  App Name                           0x000000010d116a6a +[FIRApp sendNotificationsToSDKs:] + 393
    27  App Name                           0x000000010d115a6d +[FIRApp configureDefaultAppWithOptions:sendingNotifications:] + 302
    28  App Name                           0x000000010d11570a +[FIRApp configure] + 380
    29  App Name                           0x000000010c8dcf73 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 115
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000113b0f35a -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 267
    31  UIKit                               0x0000000113b10db7 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4105
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000113b16245 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000113ed1c6c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924
    34  UIKit                               0x000000011429f3ef +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000113ed1865 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000113ed20c3 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 668
    37  UIKit                               0x000000011482fc11 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262
    38  UIKit                               0x000000011482faca -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
    39  UIKit                               0x000000011451db9c __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 420
    40  UIKit                               0x0000000114718c3e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    41  UIKit                               0x000000011451d998 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231
    42  UIKit                               0x000000011429ea4c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    43  UIKit                               0x0000000113b14ac6 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523
    44  UIKit                               0x00000001140dd523 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369
    45  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b1da158 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338
    46  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b1e2c4d __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235
    47  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011371543c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    48  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011371aaf4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    49  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b20e672 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    50  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b20e328 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464
    51  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b20e897 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9b92b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa58d31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f99dc19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f99d1ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f99ca89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    57  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000117fdf9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    58  UIKit                               0x0000000113b17d30 UIApplicationMain + 159
    59  App Name                           0x000000010c8e1b4f main + 111
    60  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113791d81 start + 1
    61  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Issue filed at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/335

Comment: I have downgraded to v 4.0.0 and my app works well now. Latest version doesn't work for me.